# How do I invade other players in Ascend

Tags: ascend-hand-of-kul

In Ascend: Hand of Kul, you invade other players games by ascending, but after ascending my champions havent actually done much of anything (mostof the time only capturing one point after being ascended for like a week). Is there a way to invade players manually or at least more often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascended champions will attack a random point that you own in the local dominion on their own, but at a slow pace (like 1 attempt per day).

You can specify a point to invade by:

- going to the map menu,
- switching to global dominion (trigger)
- going to a detail view of the area you want to invade
- put the cursor over the point you want to invade (you must own it on your local dominion to invade the global dominion)
- hit A to invade
- choose champion(s) to send
- wait for results. It could be quickly (if the invader kills the defender), 5 minutes (the defender ignores the call), or even longer (there is a queue on that point)

As far as I can tell, the game has no limit on how many times you can manually invade per day. Nor does it seem to limit how many you can send off at once.